# В чем отличия OUT и INOUT

Tags: база-данных, sql, mysql

Привет. Подскажите разницу `OUT` и `INOUT` переменных при создании процедур.

Благодарен за примеры .

Answer (score 3):

OUT описывает выходной параметр,
INOUT - параметр может использоваться и как входной, и как выходной.

Comment: можно пример ,который покажет как параметр INOUT может использоватся локально?(не изменить глобальную по отношению к процедуре )переменную?

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, значение такой переменной на входе может быть изменено внутри процедуры и возвращено в вызывающую программу.